# How to find the right testId - Testcafe Error E24

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cucumber, testcafe

Creating tests using testcafe, this is pre-existing code written:

```
When(/^I click on username button$/, async () => {
    await get TestCafeController().click(stepsHelper.getElementByTestId('user'));
});
```

getElementByTestId(dataTestId) returns:

```
Selector(`[data-testid="${dataTestId}"]`).with({ boundTestRun: getTestCafeController() });
```

'user' is the wrong test id. I'm pretty new to testing so how would I find the correct data-testid? Here's an image of the error I'm receiving:

[TestCafe Error Code: E24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2zEp.png)

I tried different data-testids and looked through the code I was testing. The app I'm testing has two different modes and I'm trying to find the id of the user button. One mode works with 'user' but the mode I'm writing a test for doesn't work with 'user'.

Comment: There are a few ways you can find the correct data-testid for the user button: 1. Inspect the element: Right-click on the user button in the app and select "Inspect element". This should open the browser's developer tools and highlight the HTML code for the button. Look for the data-testid attribute in the HTML code. 2. Search the codebase: Search the codebase for the text of the button. This may help you find where the button is being rendered, and you can look for the data-testid attribute in the code.

Comment: 3. Use the browser's element picker: Some developer tools have an element picker feature that allows you to click on an element in the app to inspect its HTML code. You can use this feature to select the user button and find the data-testid attribute.  Once you have the correct data-testid, update the line of code await getTestCafeController().click(stepsHelper.getElementByTestId('user')); to use the correct data-testid.